# Cannot post comments on sites using Facebook social plugin

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have a Facebook account that was successfully registered from behind Tor (not using my real name, of course). I am unable to post comments on sites that use the Facebook social plugin. There is no error message returned. I am able to login to Facebook, and the comment appears on my screen as having been posted, but it isn't visible to others. I have tried using one other Facebook account, but get the same results. This has been a problem with all the Tor Browser Bundle versions that I have used. I have tried disabling HTTPS Everywhere and NoScript, but it still doesn't work.

Has anyone been able to overcome this problem? Are there hidden settings in the browser that I need to change that would permit my posts to go through?

Comment: I've tried to post comments "in the open" (not using Tor) with the Facebook Social Plugin, and I get this same problem. I think this is because I refuse to give Facebook my phone number, and therefore my account has not been "verified". I will get a real "burner" phone and see if I can use it to verify the account. I tried using the Burner app for Android, but Facebook doesn't seem to want to send any verification to the phone number Burner gave me.

Comment: I have managed to post successfully in blogspot, wordpress and disqus (not using Facebook which I despise :) It takes some wrangling. Maybe with Facebook you can try in the browser settings: 1. accept all cookies from all sites 2. allow popups

Comment: I have confirmed that you need to verify your Facebook account using a phone number where you can receive a text message prior to your Facebook Social Plugin posts being visible to others. That could be where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

I think website by itself is configured to prevent access with javascript disabled or with Tor IP addresses. some sites believes that Tor IPs are spam and admin block it. Even if you disable NoScript, again, it depends on the admin of website that you visit or whoever created this facebook plugin. You should ask them to see if it is a bug and to change such behavior of plugin or website. I had the same problem with disqus, so, I had to use PC in the library if I wanted to comment, in that way, they couldn't see my personal IP address. But I don't think this question has anything to do with Tor, it has to be with facebook plugin or websites you visit.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is the case for the Facebook Social Plugins specifically?

Comment: I have posted hundred of times on disqus with Tor. It is possible.